# Getting Yesterdays Date at Exactly Midnight in PHP

Tags: php, date, cron

Should I have any issue with this?

I am setting up a cron job at EXACTLY midnight

```
0   0   *   *   *    /usr/bin/php    myscript.php
```

The script is set to define the previous day's date in MySQL timestamp format.

```
$midnightyesterday2 = (new DateTime())->setTime(0, 0);
$midnightyesterday2->modify('-1 day');
$midnightyesterday = $midnightyesterday2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

echo output:

> > 2017-04-08 00:00:00

```
$endofdayyesterday2 = (new DateTime())->setTime(23, 59, 59);
$endofdayyesterday2->modify('-1 day');
$endofdayyesterday = $endofdayyesterday2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

echo output:

> > 2017-04-08 23:59:59

Obviously this sample output is working properly because I'm doing this at 15:22:00.

Is it just paranoia in me thinking setting up a cron job at midnight could cause conflict even by a half a second if the script is for some reason run a tad fraction early.

Is there a better way to ensure yesterdays date with a script set to run at exactly midnight?

I need it to run at exactly midnight because the script is based off a MySQL `lastmodified` timestamp as my echo suggests, and even running it at 12:01 could leave some behind of additional rows are added in that minute.

Comment: Your fine, your cron job will only run once and at midnight, you don't need to worry about it at all. Really, though, it wouldn't matter if it was midnight or anytime, it only runs once.

Comment: It seems really dangerous to have a system depend on a job running at exactly midnight.  You should think of another way to accomplish your goal.

Comment: @Evan Carslake : well I know it's only going to run once, but my concern is, since it's running at midnight, the DateTime could possibly screw up and I could get duplicates. @Gordon Linoff : hence this question :)  I'm wondering if I could maybe add 12 hours to the DateTime and then set the time to `00:00:00` or if there is a better way

Comment: @BrianBruman right, but I mean, midnight only occurs once, same with any other time. 00:00::00 is no different than wanting it to run only once at say 5 o' clock 05:00:00. Midnight only lasts that second and then it is 00:00:01. You are fine...

Answer (score 7):

Please try the below code to get the yesterday's beginning and end date with exact hours.

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("yesterday")); // 2018-09-18 00:00:00

date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("today 1 sec ago")); // 2018-09-18 23:59:59
```

Comment: You can also do that by passing string to strtotime(). For Example: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2018-09-18 00:00:00"));` and  `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("2018-09-18 23:59:59"));`

Answer (score 0):

My solution (that kind of came to me in the comments) was to do the following:

Remember, the script is set to run at exactly midnight (00:00:00).

So I'm setting up a new `DateTime` object, adding 12 hours. (12:00:00)

Then after moving it 12 hours ahead, using `setTime` to set the time to 00:00:00.

Then using DateTime's `modify` again to subtract 24 hours.

```
$midnightyesterday2 = new DateTime();
$midnightyesterday2->modify('+12 hour');
$midnightyesterday2->setTime(0, 0);
$midnightyesterday2->modify('-24 hour');
$midnightyesterday = $midnightyesterday2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $midnightyesterday;
```

> > 2017-04-08 00:00:00

Same with to get the end of day yesterday result

```
$endofdayyesterday2 = new DateTime();
$endofdayyesterday2->modify('+12 hour');
$endofdayyesterday2->setTime(23, 59, 59);
$endofdayyesterday2->modify('-24 hour');
$endofdayyesterday = $endofdayyesterday2->format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
echo $endofdayyesterday;
```

> > 2017-04-08 23:59:59

I'm not saying this is the best way to do this, this idea just kind of came to me. But it seems to maybe add a kind of fail safe to what I'm trying to do.

I'll leave this open for a while if someone has a better or more proper solution.